# Selecting the product image for the specific webshop through phpmyadmin

Tags: product, admin, database, image, product-images

At the product specific management page ("Catalog > Manage product > any product") you see the "image"tab. Please click on it.

At the left sidebar you can see: Choose store view "Default values". When you click on the dropdown menu, and choose for example "Webshop_A". Then you'll see a table with the images inside the cells. You also see a checkbox at the following columns:

- Base Image
- Small Image
- Thumbnail

The admin has the ability to choose an image or to use the default value by unchecking or checking the checkboxes in the column.

I would like to uncheck the checkbox at "Use Default Value", and to check them at a specific image. Obviously, you can do that by using the checkboxes in the table. You can do it like the screenshot below:

[image]

I would like to do this not through the backend, but through phpmyadmin. I took a look at a table:

```
catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

But this table does not cater the checkbox settings.

Does anyone have the right know-how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox is checked when you have a value for a specific attribute (`image` for example) only for the store with the id `0` (default store).
So if you insert a line in the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` for a product but with a different store id than 0, the checkbox will be automatically unchecked.